# Setting up intellij debugger to be able to break inside or step thru an NPM script

Tags: javascript, node.js, debugging, intellij-idea, npm

I have an NPM script that runs and ultimately generates a file in the repo.

How do I go about configuring the debugger to run it so that I am able to do such things as break inside/step thru its code after I run it on the command line.

Answer (score 1):

If you like to start your script in command line and not from the IDE, you need using **NodeJS Remote Debug** run configuration:

- modify your NPM script to make sure that your Node.js app is run with debugger, like:

  "scripts": {
      "start": "node --debug-brk=5858 build/app.js"
  }
- create **NodeJS Remote Debug** run configuration, specify `5858` as a **Port** there
- run `npm start` in console, start the debugger in the IDE